# WebApi BaseController - Checking User

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following BaseApiController:

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public readonly Current _current { get; private set; }
}
```

All my `ApiControllers` inherit from this one.

I need to do a validation in all of my methods inside my `ApiControllers`, that checks if the userId passed match the current HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.

```
[Route("{userId}/cars")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCars(int userId)
{
    if (userId != _current.UserId)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,                     "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to do it on the BaseApiController, so that I can avoid doing this validation on all of the endpoints that receive the userId as argument?

Comment: What should the validation actually do? You could just make a protected method and call that. Attributes might be interesting as well to take a look at.

Comment: The validation is to check that the token/claim on the pipeline match the {userId} sent from the Api consumer.

Comment: I know what is being validated but what action should be performed? Is this action the same every time it's called?

Comment: Oh sorry. It returns always the same ``return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
                    "Unauthorized");``

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I updated my question. Maybe it helps to understand what I am talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom validation attribute based on [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to achieve what you need.

For your case it can look like this:

```
public class UserAccessCheckAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as BaseApiController;
        object requestUserIdObj;

        if (controller != null && actionContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("userId", out requestUserIdObj))
        {
            var userId = (int) requestUserIdObj;

            if (userId != controller._current.UserId)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Unauthorized");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can decorate either controllers or specific actions where you need to perform user id check with this attribute:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
[UserAccessCheck] //check user id for all actions in controller
public class AccountController : BaseApiController
{
    //....
}

public class ValuesController : BaseApiController
{
    //....
    [UserAccessCheck] //check user id for specific action only
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

After that no additional code in your actions required

Comment: It's a good idea, but I am getting this error : ``System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'CreateErrorResponse' and no extension method 'CreateErrorResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' could be found`` on the **actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse**

Comment: @user3362714 check is you have System.Net.Http namespace in your usings